# Excel formula not working with vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

This is an odd one.  Here is the formula.

```
=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(C255,'Task Data'!$A$4:$AT$3005,39,'Task Data'!$AM$4:$AM$3005)=1,"Non-Compliant","Compliant"),"Compliant")
```

The issue is when the function looks in 'Task Data' for what C255 is and there are two of them (in two different rows) it appears it only works if 1 is in the top row, i.e. it results and shows "Compliant".  If the 1 is in the lower row, it still shows "Compliant" but it should be "Non-Compliant".  It appears it is not seeing the second 1 in the second row.  Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: You mean to say that the value in C255 is available in both data ranges A4:AT3005 & AM4:AM3005 and you are trying to extract both ?

Comment: I think your formula should written like this `=IF(VLOOKUP(C255,AM4:AM3005,1,TRUE)=1, VLOOKUP(C255,A4:AT3005,39,TRUE), NA())`

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP has a fourth parameter, TRUE or FALSE.

You need to set it depending on if you look for an *exact match* (FALSE), or if you have sorted data and want to *interpolate* between the next best value (TRUE).
The default is TRUE, which is a common issue.